# Getting only one post per category

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy

I am getting only one post .when I two post assigned in one category .
Please let me know how to get all post of a category.

```
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
    <!--<div id="<?php //echo $term_id = $term->term_id;?>" class="tabcontent"><!-->
          <?php //echo $term_id = $term->term_id;?>
    <?php
                             //loop the names of the slugs for the portfolio_categories
    $terms = get_terms( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ));
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $slug= $term->slug;
      $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $args = array(                          
                                            'post_type' => 'Portfolio',
                                            'portfolio_categories' =>$slug,  
                                            'orderby' => 'ID',
                                            'order' => 'DESC',
                                            'hide_empty' => 1,
                                            'posts_per_page' => 6
                                        );

                                        $posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                    if (have_posts()) :    
                                  while (   $posts_query->have_posts() ) : $posts_query->the_post();
    //echo '<div id="'.$term_id .'" class="tabcontent1">';
                                  ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $term_id = $term->term_id;?>" class="tabcontent">
       <?php echo '<div class="col-1-3">';?>
        <!--<div class="col-1-3"><!-->
       <?php echo $term_id = $term->term_id;?>     
       <?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );?>
       <div id="<?php //echo $term_id = $term->term_id;?>" class="wrap-col" >
                        <div class="item-container">
                            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" data-fancybox-group= gallery>   
                          <div class="overlay text-center">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                              <h4>BAKER CANISTER PUMP</h4>
                            </div>
                          </div><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0];?>"></a> </div>
                      </div>
           <!-- </div><!-->
     <?php echo '</div>';//echo '</div>';?>
     </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;endif;  wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

after
var_dump( $posts_query);
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(                          
'post_type' => 'Portfolio',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories',
        'terms' => $slug,
        'field' => 'slug',
    )
),
'orderby' => 'ID',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

Comment: lukgoh@removed but no luck

Comment: ukgoh@you there? bro

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: lukgoh@thanks bro but it's not working gonna die right now . I have no idea how to solve this ,please help me

Comment: Haha, don't stress mate lets work this out. You should check to see if it is pulling the correct data.

Use var_dump($slug); to see what that is returning.
Then use var_dump($posts_query); to see if that has more than one result...

Comment: lukgoh@ I am working on around 48 hours and unable to solve this. yes I am pulling correct data. only one post showing for every category ,if assign 2 post on same category ,then its again showing one post,

Comment: Can you do the var_dumps and post links so I can see?

Comment: lukgoh @I am doing I am  on local , trying to take screen shot ,am sorry i have not server .

Comment: lukgoh@please see the updated question,please help me

Comment: lukgoh@you  only hope for me .you there?

Comment: Hmm, thats a weird output. Give me some time to think.

Comment: What code exists before this? What terms are you looping through, before looping through more terms?

Comment: lukgoh@this code is done by me according to requirement, if you agree then i can send  custom post and taxonomy code

Comment: Yeah, send it lukgoh@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: please see this your mail